# Insufficient resources error while upgrading to Sitecore 9.1.1

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-commerce, upgrade

I am getting insufficient resources error:

> net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

while upgrading to Sitecore 9.1.1.

Any thoughts how to fix this error?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide errors from Sitecore logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to CPU utilization reaching 100% . When I ran the same installation on a virtual machine with higher configuration, it worked fine